# The elliptic curve $y^2 = x^3 + 2015x - 2015$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

Consider the elliptic curve 
\begin{equation*}
E: y^2 = x^3 + 2015x - 2015~\text{over}~\mathbb{Q}.
\end{equation*}
I want to prove that $|E(\mathbb{F}_7)| = 12$, that $|E(\mathbb{F}_{19})| = 19$ and that $E(\mathbb{Q})_{\text{tors}}$ is equal to the trivial group.

I'm completely lost. Any suggestions?

Comment: When you say you are "completely lost"... Could you be more specific? Do you know how to calculate the number of points over a finite field? Or are you stuck on how to calculate the torsion subgroup from that information?

Comment: So far, I've been able to calculate the discriminant, but that's about it. This stuff is all very new to me, I'm afraid.

Comment: Do you know what $E(\mathbb{F}_7)$ is?

Comment: Yes, it's the elliptic curve $y^2 = x^3 + 2015x -2015$ over the field with 7 elements.

Comment: So you just need to calculate the number of points in that curve, working modulo 7 (and don't forget the point at infinity).

Comment: I know that, I just don't know how. It seems a bit excessive to check every possibility, especially for the case $\mathbb{F}_{19}$.

Comment: Indeed. I would not imagine somebody wants you to compute $E(\mathbb{F}_{19})$ by hand. You can use Sage or Magma for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following are some bits and pieces from Section 2.6 of [my book](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=stml-58). Here I will demonstrate what the OP is trying to do, but with another elliptic curve. Hopefully the OP can replicate this for the elliptic curve above.

Let $E/\mathbb{Q}$ be the elliptic curve $y^2=x^3+3$. Its minimal discriminant is $\Delta_E=-3888=-2^4\cdot 3^5$. Thus, the only primes of bad reduction are $2$ and $3$ and $\widetilde{E}/\mathbb{F}_p$ is smooth for all $p\geq 5$. For $p=5$, there are precisely $6$ points on $\widetilde{E}(\mathbb{F}_5)$, namely
$$\widetilde{E}(\mathbb{F}_5)=\{ \widetilde{O}, (1,2), (1,3),
(2,1), (2,4),(3,0) \},$$ where all the coordinates should be regarded as congruences modulo $5$. Thus, $N_5=6$, which is in the range given by [Hasse's bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse%27s_theorem_on_elliptic_curves):
$$ 1.5278\ldots = 5+1-2\sqrt{5}< N_5 < 5+1+2\sqrt{5}=10.4721\ldots .$$
Similarly, one can verify that $N_7 = 13$.

Next, let us quote an important result we will use:

**Proposition** [Silverman's "The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves", Ch. VII, Prop. 3.1]
*Let $E/\mathbb{Q}$ be an elliptic curve, $p$ a prime number and $m$ a natural number not divisible by $p$. Suppose that $E/\mathbb{Q}$ has good reduction at $p$. Then the reduction map modulo $p$,
$$E(\mathbb{Q})[m] \longrightarrow \widetilde{E}(\mathbb{F}_p),$$
is an injective homomorphism of abelian groups. In particular, the number of elements of $E(\mathbb{Q})[m]$ divides the number of elements of $\widetilde{E}(\mathbb{F}_p)$.*

Let us go back to the example $E/\mathbb{Q} \colon y^2=x^3+3$. Above we have seen that $N_5=6$ and $N_7=13$, and $E/\mathbb{Q}$ has bad reduction only at $2$ and $3$.

If $q\neq 5,7$ is a prime number, then $E(\mathbb{Q})[q]$ is trivial. Indeed, the Proposition implies that $|E(\mathbb{Q})[q]|$ divides $N_5=6$ and also $N_7=13$. Thus, $|E(\mathbb{Q})[q]|$ must divide $\gcd(6,13)=1$.

In the case of $q=5$, we know that $|E(\mathbb{Q})[5]|$ divides $N_7=13$. Moreover, by Lagrange's theorem from group theory, if $E(\mathbb{Q})[p]$ is non-trivial, then $p$ divides $|E(\mathbb{Q})[p]|$ (in fact $E(\mathbb{Q})[p]$ is always a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$). Since $5$ does not divide $13$, it follows that $E(\mathbb{Q})[5]$ must be trivial. Similarly, one can show that $E(\mathbb{Q})[7]$ is trivial, and we conclude that $E(\mathbb{Q})_\text{torsion}$ is trivial.

Comment: So actually, you don't use Hasse's bound (you just calculate $N_5$ by hand) or did you use it perhaps for $N_7$?

Comment: No, I calculated both $N_5$ and $N_7$ by hand. I just verified that they agree with the bounds.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, there are no efficient ways to calculate the number of points of an elliptic curve over a finite field? Suppose you look at $E(\mathbb{F}_{997})$ or even larger, you will need a mathematical software program? Hasse's bound could narrow the possibilities I guess, but still leaves a very wide range..